# Testing binary outcomes with linear regression - R^2 false positives?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, coefficient-of-determination

There are many reasons not to test binary outcomes with a linear regression (as opposed to a logistic regression). If one did though, is there any scenario in which the F-test for the coefficient of determination ($R^2$) would yield a false-positive? That is, could the F-test be significant when in fact none of the variables in the model would be significant if one tested the model with a logistic regression?

For example, if one ran the first model instead of the second:

```
library(palmerpenguins)
data(package = 'palmerpenguins')
dat = penguins

model_linear = lm(as.numeric(sex) ~ ., data = dat)
model_log = glm(sex ~ ., data = dat,family = "binomial")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try it in a simulation!**

> I got it to happen five times, so it is possible, yes.

```r
set.seed(2024)
N <- 50
R <- 1000
counter <- 0
for (i in 1:R){
  
  # Siulate data
  #
  x <- runif(N, 0, 1)
  y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
  
  # Fit logistic and linear probability models
  #
  LR <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial)
  LPM <- lm(y ~ x)
  
  # Extract the p-values
  #
  p_lr <- summary(LR)$coef[2, 4]
  p_lpm <- summary(LPM)$coef[2, 4]
  
  # Increase the counter if the linear probability model is
  # significant at the 0.05-level but the logistic regression isn't
  #
  if (p_lr > 0.05 & p_lpm <= 0.05){
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}

# Print how many times the linear probability model has a significant slope 
# coefficient yet the logistic regression does not (assuming the 0.05-level)
#
print(counter)
```

You can tweak the above to include multiple features.

```r
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 50
R <- 1000
counter <- 0
for (i in 1:R){
 
  # Siulate data
  #
  X <- matrix(runif(N * 5), N, 5)
  y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
 
  # Fit logistic and linear probability models
  #
  LR <- glm(y ~ X, family = binomial)
  LPM <- lm(y ~ X)
 
  # Fit null models (intercept-only models)
  #
  LR0 <- glm(y ~ 1, family = binomial)
  LPM0 <- lm(y ~ 1)
 
  # Extract the p-values, using a likelihood ratio test
  #
  p_lr <- lmtest::lrtest(LR0, LR)$`Pr(>Chisq)`[2]
  p_lpm <- lmtest::lrtest(LPM0, LPM)$`Pr(>Chisq)`[2]
 
  # Increase the counter if the linear probability model is
  # significant at the 0.05-level but the logistic regression isn't
  #
  if (p_lr > 0.05 & p_lpm <= 0.05){
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}

# Print how many times the linear probability model is significant
# yet the logistic regression is not (assuming the 0.05-level)
#
print(counter) # I get two times
```

There are further variants of this simulation that you can do.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to become increasingly uncommon with larger Ns.